# Null values getting inserted in one to Many relation mapping in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

When i am running this code and try to save userinformation class with some vehicles.  values getting inserted in  userinformation table   properly but in vehicle table null values getting inserted in foreign key column

/** User information Class *******/

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;    
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade;

@Entity
public class Userinformation {

    int id;
    String username;
    Set<Vehicle> vehicles = new HashSet<Vehicle>();



    public Userinformation() {
    }

    public Userinformation(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Userinformation(int id,String username,Set<Vehicle> vehicles){

        this.id=id;
        this.username=username;
        this.vehicles=vehicles;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    @Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "userinformation")
    public Set<Vehicle> getVehicles() {
        return vehicles;
    }

    public void setVehicles(Set<Vehicle> vehicles) {
        this.vehicles = vehicles;
    }

}
```

/************** Vehicle Class ********************/

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;


@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    int id;
    String vehicleName;
    Userinformation userinformation;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getVehicleName() {
        return vehicleName;
    }

    public void setVehicleName(String vehicleName) {
        this.vehicleName = vehicleName;
    }


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",referencedColumnName="id")
    public Userinformation getUserinformation() {
        return userinformation;
    }



    public void setUserinformation(Userinformation userinformation) {
        this.userinformation = userinformation;
    }

}
```

/************** Output ******************/

Userinformation table

### id | username|

1  | magic   |

Vehicle Table

### id | vehicleName |user_id |

1  | BMW         | NULL   |
2  | Audi        | NULL   |

Comment: When you add a `Vehicle` to `vehicles` make sure you call `setUserinformation` on it

Comment: it works if  i set value of userinformation reference variable of vehicle instance by calling setUserinformation method of it.